# JS For-Loop Cloning Too Many Times

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

EDITED: (I identified the problem that was previously being discussed in the comments)

my code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
            $(".image-wrap").clone().appendTo(".container").attr('id', ("reason" + i));
        }

</script>
```

for some reason, when I use this approach, I get a div with class of "image-wrap" and ID of "reason0" as expected, but then there are two instances of "image-wrap" with "reason1" and then four instances of "image-wrap" with "reason2," and so on and so forth. What's wrong with my loop?

Comment: what does console show?

Comment: please show the HTML

Comment: have you tried with document.querySelectorAll? like `document.querySelectorAll( '#reason0.front' );`? never tried like this so i didn't put as an answer

Comment: Since only one element is allowed to have same id, you won't need the `getElementsByClassName` selector

Comment: @IiroP Inside of the div that has an id of "reasonX", there is another div that has a class of "front." are you suggesting that I can target these front divs another way?

Comment: if you have the same class on all of them then yes as per your line getElementsByClassName("front")[0] you will do document.getElementsByClassName("front")[0] ... [1] .. [2] and so on.

Comment: @Kaddath — That selector does something very different to the code in the question.

Comment: @laroy — You need to provide a [mcve]. Showing use a fragment of code with no context that you say **works** isn't very helpful!

Comment: @Quentin you're right, i get tired it seems, something like '#reason0 .front' would do then (the space)

Comment: @Kaddath — I don't see any situation where that would work when the gEBId+gEBCN approach doesn't.

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0p9mzLr/) for this but it seems to work

Comment: @IiroP — `getElementsByClassName` searches the **descendants** of the element it is called on. It doesn't filter the element it is called on.

Comment: @IiroP — That's why we've been asking to see a [mcve] including the HTML. The problem isn't with the JS.

Comment: @hungerstar — There's no practical difference between that querySelectorAll code and the code in the question.

Comment: @IiroP That's essentially the same approach I'm taking; however, when I get to the 2nd index, the text doesn't show up. In the console it appears, but on my screen its nowhere to be found.

Comment: @Quentin there is a difference, with  gEBId+gEBCN, if first element is not found, it will throw an error, because you gEBCN on null, anyway, yes, this is a bit pointless

Comment: @Quentin I identified that the problem is with the way I'm cloning the divs, though I'm not sure why my for loops is behaving this way. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: `but then there are two instances of "image-wrap" with "reason1" and then four instances of "image-wrap" with "reason2," and so on and so forth` because you are cloning...

Comment: @Lal I can see that as the result, but I'm not sure why this loop is doing that. When I read this, I see the original image-wrap being cloned 5 times, with each instance getting a unique ID of reason0, reason1, reason2, reason3, and reason4.

Comment: @Lal ohh, I understand it now. Because the script is targeting every instance of the class "image-wrap." Is there somewhere I could target the first instance of it instead of all instances?

Comment: Try `$(".image-wrap:first").clone().appendTo(".container").attr('id', ("reason" + i));` instead of `$(".image-wrap").clone().appendTo(".container").attr('id', ("reason" + i));`

Comment: @Lal you're exactly right. Thank you!

Comment: @laroy Great...Glad that it helped you..I'l post that as my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`there are two instances of "image-wrap" with "reason1" and then four instances of "image-wrap" with "reason2," and so on and so forth`

is because you have used `$(".image-wrap").clone()`. Actually, the script is targeting every instance of the class "image-wrap."

So, if you need to clone only the first instance of `.image-wrap`, then you could use the `:first` pseudo-selector. See the updated script below..

```
$(".image-wrap:first").clone().appendTo(".container").attr('‌​id', ("reason" + i));
```

Read more about `:first` pseudo-selector [here](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)